# Binding an image to ImageBrush

Tags: c#, xaml

i am having an issue while trying to bind an image to an ImageSource. I have tried some of the other fix on stackoverflow but none of them works.

I seem to get an error on this line saying that collection "Items" must be empty.

```
ImageList.ItemsSource = List;
```

The bind works well while using the "url" member of the FlickrData class.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView  x:Name="ImageList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <Rectangle Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding imageBinding}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

---

**FlickrData Class**:

```
public class FlickrData
{
    public String url { get; set;}

    public FlickrData(Photo photo)
    {
        url = photo.SmallUrl;
    }

    public ImageBrush imageBinding
      {
        get
          {
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
            return brush;
          }
      }
}
```

---

**MainWindow class**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<FlickrData> List = new ObservableCollection<FlickrData>();
    public static Flickr flickr = new Flickr("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SearchWithInput(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var options = new PhotoSearchOptions { Tags = SearchInput.Text, PerPage = 20, Page = 1 };
        PhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options);

        List.Clear();
        foreach (Photo photo in photos)
        {
            String flickrUrl = photo.WebUrl;
            Console.WriteLine("Photo {0} has title {1} with url {2}", photo.PhotoId, photo.Title, photo.WebUrl);
            List.Add(new FlickrData(photo));
        }
        ImageList.ItemsSource = List;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to clean up the process

1. Change your XAML's `ListView` to `ItemsSource="{Binding List}"` which  only needs to be done once.
2. Remove the now redundant `ImageList.ItemsSource = List;`

The list control will update itself accordingly because an `ObservableCollection` sends notifications of the change which are subscribed to by the list control.

Comment: It seems that `ItemsSource` is not found in type `ImageBrush`

Comment: Not for `ImageBrush` but for the `ListView`.